# ionic 6 - Chat Screen - Keep scroll to bottom - Dynamic height components

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework

I have an Angular Ionic 6 app with a chat screen & when it loads up I want the ion-content to be scrolled to the bottom.

I know how to scroll the content to the bottom using `this.ionContent.scrollToBottom();` but the problem is some of the messages have to load in dynamic content and have a variable height.

What would be the best way of making sure after all of those messages and components are loaded in THEN it scrolls the chat to the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem a few months ago. Sometimes a lot of messages were loaded, and the scroll didn't reach all the way down.

I worked it around with this function in my `utils.service.ts`:

```js
 async goToBottom(content:IonContent, times:number=1){
   for(let i=0; i<times; i++){
     await this.wait(200);
     await content.scrollToBottom(200)    
   }
 }
```

So I can call it like this:

```js
this.utilsSvc.goToBottom(this.content, 3);
```

and make sure it always arrives the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Miguel, so it looks like you're just polling the scrollToBottom for a bit in the beginning. I will give this a try - thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: Perfect! I hope it helps. Please mark the answer as correct if it solve your problem :)